# disabled input stops event bubbling

Tags: javascript, events, input, event-bubbling

If I've got an input element (for example: `<input type="text" disabled="disabled">` ), this input stops the mouseover event bubbling. If I remove the disabled attribute, the container element of the input gets the mousemove event.

How can I get event bubbling working on disabled inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible. Disabled input elements sink no events. My advice would be to make your input appear as "disabled" via CSS and set it to read only to prevent modification. That way they will still sink all mouse events and bubbling will work just fine.